# Please help me understand this PHP hack,how can i bypass this re

Tags: php

I found a php code ,It can only include a file for this topic, but this file contains numbers. It has to be bypass for this re.

I tried to use file_put_contents to generate files with other filenames, but only the code in index. PHP could be run.
So I think only bypass this re,and no race condition

```
<?php    
 include_once("fl2g.php"); 
 $filename = $_GET['filename']; 
 $filename = $_GET['content']; 
    if(preg_match("/[^a-z\.]/", $filename) == 1) { 
        echo "Hacker"; 
        die(); 
    } 
    $files = scandir('./');  
    foreach($files as $file) { 
        if(is_file($file)){ 
            if ($file !== "index.php") { 
                unlink($file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    file_put_contents($filename, $content ); 
   ?>
```

I expect bypass this re

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the regex states:
"^" Match any character that is not in the set "a-z." (lowercase "a" through "z", and a period ".")

the return value of Preg_match() is 1 if false or 0 if true.

```
if (preg_match("\[^a-z\.]\", "abc.xyz") == 1) 
// would return true(?) because preg_match() returns false , but false = 1; so it returns true. i think :/
```

then it appears to delete all the files in the directory?

edit: to add a number to the file name you can just append stuff like this

```
$filename = "001".$filename; //makes "001ZZZ"
```

im kinda rusty with php/regex

Comment: yes,it will delete all the files expect index.php

Answer (score 0):

Just add numbers to regexp.

```
if(preg_match("/[^a-z0-9\.]/", $filename) == 1) {
```

Comment: emmmm....i wan to bypass this regex.then add number to filename.